# Tika and parsing data with row and col spans

Tags: parsing, xhtml, apache-tika

I am searching for this for the past 2 days but its difficult to find. but the problem here is when you search for col spans in google with any word, different and variant documents will show that are irrelevant.

The question: is it possible to use tika apache parser, to retrieve or get parsed data from different type of documents with the col spans and row span as xhtml. if yes is there a tutorial or any document that can help me with that.

Comment: Tika will happily parse a range of table containing file formats, and give you the table as XHTML. Is that what you want? If not, could you perhaps edit your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, out o the box.

You would need to extend the base library used to parse spreadsheets to get this information into the Tika output.

An alternative would be to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Tika will happily convert Excel spreadsheets into table-based XHTML! What made you think it wouldn't?

Comment: Agree, Tika is able to render simple tables, where cells do not span multiple rows or multiple columns.  In our experiments, as soon as this aspect was introduced, then the resulting XHTML lost fidelity with the original spreadsheet in terms of layout of the rows/columns - which was important to our purpose.  Given Tika's job is to extract text from documents - to be honest we were asking too much of it, an thus switched to other mechanised.

Comment: Did you think to raise an enhancement request? Ideally including a small sample file and a failing unit test? If no-one flags up a problem, then most likely the project will never realise!

Comment: It's not a problem.  We were looking to use Tika for a purpose that it wasn't intented (IMHO).

Comment: It's still worth raising as in issue. The Tika community can then decide if it's something appropriate or not, but without the report and the file that shows it, no-one there will even know!